# Iterating over array in a try…catch…finally results in "MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a function that connects to a Mongo database, then finds documents in the database that match an array.

The function is actually working fine and the data I want is being found and returned by checkIfExist(). However, the function returns an error in the console despite it working. The error is "MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended", as is shown below.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong here.

The error:

[image]

The function:

```
async function main() {
  const uri = 'URL';
  const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
  const pairData = [`_EURAUD_data`, `_EURCAD_data`, `_EURCHF_data`];
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db('daily-ohlc').collection('ohlcs');

  try {
    const checkIfExist = async () => {
      pairData.map(pair => {
        const findstuff = db.find({ _id: pair._id }).toArray();
        console.log(`${findstuff}`);
      });
    };
    await checkIfExist();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    console.log(`closing timne`);
    await client.close();
  }
}
main().catch(console.error);
```

Things I have tried.

1. I have tried adding a two-second setTimeout to the await.client.close() and I do not get the error. So it seems like the client is closing too quickly.
2. Replacing the .map in checkIfExist() so it doesn't iterate and it works without error.

Comment: return  pairData.map...you are not returning a value from the map function and do not need to place your await just outside your try block. Then, when you call main() use then to log the resolve object if the promise returns and then you can use catch to log the error if the promise is rejected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a simple as wrapping the Array.map in a Promise.all method. When I did this the Array.map completed before moving on to the finally block.

```
async function main() {
  const uri = 'URL';
  const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

  try {
    await client.connect();
    const pairData = await cleanObject();
    const db = client.db('daily-ohlc').collection('ohlcs');
    const updateOrCreate = async () =>
      //needs to be in a promise
      Promise.all(
        pairData.map(async pair => {
          const check = db
            .find({ _id: pair._id, 'data.date': pair.data[0].date })
            .toArray()
            .then(value => value.length === 0);

          if (check) {
            return db
              .updateOne({ _id: pair._id, 'data.date': pair.data[0].date }, { $set: { 'data.$': pair.data[0] } }, { upsert: true })
              .then(result => `UPDATED DAY: ${pair._id}`)
              .catch(er => console.log(er));
          }
          return db
            .updateOne({ _id: pair._id }, { $push: { data: { $each: [pair.data[0]], $position: 0 } } }, { upsert: true })
            .then(result => `ADDED DAY: ${pair._id}`)
            .catch(er => console.log(er));
        })
      );
    console.log(await updateOrCreate());
    await updateOrCreate();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    console.log(`sever connection closing...`);
    await client.close();
  }
}
main().catch(error => console.log(error));
```